Unable to upload excel file (from memory buffer) to GCS bucket
I am building a buffer through a file upload by the user.
const chunks = [];
for await (const chunk of data) {
  chunks.push(chunk);
}
const fullData = Buffer.concat(chunks);
const gcsUrl = await uploadInputFile({
  buffer: fullData,
  filename: `myfile.xlsx`,
});

Just want to be able to upload this buffer (in memory) as a file in GCS bucket.
const uploadInputFile = async ({ buffer, filename }: { buffer: Buffer; filename: string }) => {
  await storage
    .bucket("bucket-name")
    .file(`input_files/${filename}`)
    .save(buffer, {resumable: false});

  return file.cloudStorageURI.href;
};

I have tried adding options with the save function to upload the excel file (even though I should be able to upload any type of file without specifying the content type):

.save(buffer, {resumable: false})
.save(buffer, {resumable: false, contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"})
Without any options .save(buffer)

But I'm getting this error when the client library tries to POST a file:
<p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

The same kind of code works if I use a PDF file and content type:
await storage
    .bucket("docflow-files")
    .file(`input_files/${filename}`)
    .save(buffer, {resumable: false, contentType: "application/pdf"});


Please edit the question to show a complete minimal reproducible example of the code that generates the error.  We need to be able to see how you are creating data and run that code for ourselves.

Also, the API documentation for save() suggests that it is just a wrapper around another method.  Did you try to use that other method directly instead?

@DougStevenson Please edit the link in your 2nd comment, it points to the link specified in the first comment. The data buffer is coming through a file upload, and I have already validated that the buffer has the right contents, so it would be pointless to share the huge amount of code/logic behind that. Any file can be converted to a buffer to reproduce this.
